# Flexbox text running together

Tags: css

I'm trying to make little "cards" that contain an icon, small header, and then descriptive text. However, all my text is running together right next to the image:

[image]

Any thoughts/suggestions as to why this is happening?

```css
.tool-grid {
  padding: 0 1rem 1rem 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.tool-grid a {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex: 0 1 35%;
  border: 1px solid dimgrey;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

.tool-grid a:hover {
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px #888;
  transition: .3s;
}

.tool-grid-cell {
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 1 35%;
  padding: 0 10px;
  color: #000;
}

.tool-grid-cell img {
  align-self: center;
  max-width: 32px;
  max-height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="tool-grid">
  <a href="#">
    <div class="tool-grid-cell">
      <img src="source">
      <p>Text</p>
      <p>More text</p>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because the default `display: flex;` will horizontally align immediate child elements by default, to prevent this you need to wrap both your child elements in a separate div. Flex behavior will not extend anything beyond the second child level.

Try wrap your text in a div:

```
<div class="tool-grid-cell">
    <img src="source">
    <div>
       <p>Text</p>
       <p>More text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. That works up until the window begins to shrink. Around maybe the 700px mark, the text jumps back up right next to the "header" text. I'm not sure if that gets resolved through a media query?

Comment: I think there are other media query is overwriting your css, From the snippet you provided works fine though

Comment: There isn't though... not sure what you're seeing, but the text is all running together for me.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things pushing the content together:

1. You don't need the `display:flex`on the a-tag as you can already position the children using the div with the class `tool-grid-cell`.
2. You use `flex: 0 1 35%;` on both the a-tag and the `tool-grid-cell`. This results in the content of the a-tag only having a width of 35%, pushing the elements together even further.

I also added a `space-between`, which places the elements nicely in the container and provides the result you have been looking for.

```css
.tool-grid {
    padding: 0 1rem 1rem 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}

.tool-grid a {
    border: 1px solid dimgrey;
    border-radius: 3px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    width: 35%;
}

.tool-grid a:hover {
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px #888;
    transition: .3s;
}

.tool-grid-cell {
    display: flex;
    padding: 0 10px;
    color: #000;
    justify-content:space-between;
}

.tool-grid-cell img {
    align-self: center;
    max-width: 32px;
    max-height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="tool-grid">
    <a href="#">
        <div class="tool-grid-cell">
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50">
            <p>Text</p>
            <p>More text</p>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Gotcha. I should clarify that the result I'm looking for is where the image and a header are aligned next to each other then description text underneath that.

Comment: I figured it was pretty apparent what the desired output would be with the screen shot.